# SwiftUI Realm @Published property

Tags: mongodb, swiftui, realm, combine

I have the following class:

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var isPremium: Bool = false
    @Published private var subscriptionType: String = "Trial"
    
    private var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    init() {
        $subscriptionType
            .map { type in
                if (type == "Trial" || type == "Subscription_3m") {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
            .assign(to: \.isPremium, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to persist this `user` in a Realm DB. So the class would look something like this:

```
class User: Object {
    @Published private(set) var isPremium: Bool = false
    @Persisted private var subscriptionType: String = "Trial"
    
    private var cancellables = [AnyCancellable]()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        $subscriptionType
            .map { type in
                if (type == "Trial" || type == "Subscription_3m") {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
            .assign(to: \.isPremium, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `$` notation of the `subscriptionType` property is no longer valid now that the property is wrapped as `@Persisted` i.s.o `@Published`

How can I observe changes to `subscriptionType` like in the original `user` to be able to change the value of `isPremium` when a change comes through?

Answer (score 0):

You could try ditching the Combine approach all together and use a classic approach with a setter method:

```
@Persisted private var subscriptionType: String = "Trial"{
        didSet{
            if (subscriptionType == "Trial" || subscriptionType == "Subscription_3m") {
                isPremium = true
            }
            isPremium = false
        }
    }
```